# Forward call internally, including handling cookies, in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a spring boot rest controller (note: not a MVC controller) with to endpoints.
The client should call one of them first, then immediately call the second one.

For this second call I need the cookies that the first one sets.

Is it possible to forward the call internally, but including the cookies, just as if the client did two calls.

The purpose is of course to save the client one round trip.

Rewriting the code to just skip the second calls is not possible, this question is about the possibility to short cut the client, not changing the application logic.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't call you second controller with i.e. RestTemplate and loopback address? You still can set the cookie in first request (controller1 -> controller2) but not in standard way (like set-cookie). You can do it with header: `httpHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.COOKIE, "key1=value1");` Second controller will recognize it and create proper javax.servlet.http.Cookie object.

Comment: So you propose actually doing the call from within the first resource through a rest client, setting all cookies and paths manually. 

This was not what I was looking for, but it's of course possible.

Comment: yes, exactly. Another option is to use `HTTP Status Code = 302` but it will cause one additional round trip.

Comment: Yes, and it put's a requirement on the client. Not all my clients are browsers.

Comment: in that case, I don't see other option but to call it with rest client. The point is that each request that is coming to your @RestController has to go though `FilterChain` that populates all our "fancy" objects, like security, parameters, etc.. I would not recommend you to avoid those Filters (since your controller can be executed alone (otherwise it is not controller but just a method).. If you need a code snippet, I can post it as an answer (I tried it and it works)